# iOS itunes connect valid architectures and Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, architecture, app-store-connect

I've begun to use testflight beta distribution on Apple, but when I intend to download the App in an iPad Air 2, itunes shows that app isn't compatible with this device (although I can run the app from the Xcode 6.1).

The architectures I'm using are showing in the next image:
[image]

But, on itunes connect this is what I can see:

[image]

Why arm64 and armv7 are 'Architectures not compatible'?

Thank you.